# How can authenticated users of a site join a group implemented using Groups module?

Tags: users

#### Pre-requisite knowledge:

I am using **Group** module to implement "**Group**" functionality on my drupal site similar to what **Organic Groups** module implements. I have a **user role** *community-leader* whose users have been granted the permission (under **People > Permissions**) - *Technology : Create New Group* so that they **can create new groups** of type *Technology*, but **normal authenticated users** have not been granted this permission so they **cannot create groups**.
**Group** module provides **separate permissions** on its **configuration/overview page** under **Group Roles**. These **group roles** are for users involved in a particular group. In my case, users who create the group (essentially of *Community-leader* role or a user-role with *higher permissions*) are assigned *Group-leader role* and then there is a *Group-member role* supposed to be assigned to users who will join the group created thereafter.
For these roles (both *Group-leader* and *Group-member*), permissions like *Join Group, Request Group Membership*, etc. are disabled (no checkbox available instead a 'x' sign is present). I believe this is because since a *Group-leader* created a group, he automatically joined the group and there is no meaning of these permissions for him.
**Note:** The above roles (both *Group-leader* and *Group-member*) are *global group roles*, not *group-type specific roles*.

#### Problem Statement

An authenticated user on my site is unable to access a particular **group's** page and thus has no way available to join the **group**. There is no granular(specific) permission available for this purpose.
Moreover, even *Group-leader* or *Group-member* role users cannot access **groups** other then their own **group**. How to allow that?
Could someone please guide me on **Group Access Control** for a better understanding?

[image: Screenshot of People > Permissions]

[image: Group Role - Group-leader permissions]

Answer (score 0):

**Drupal 7**

- Download and activate Group.
- Activate submodules Group add (gadd) and Group node (gnode).
- Click on Group that now appears in your menu bar next to Content (/admin/group). This is the main overview for administering Group, here is where new functionality will appear when you activate more submodules.
- Go to Group Types, in a tab on the page (/admin/group/type)
- Add a group type, you only have to choose a name
- Click "edit permissions" (/admin/group/type/manage/partner/permissions)
- Activate suitable permissions. "Outsider" are logged in users that are not part of the group. Add at least view and add permissions for one content type for members, and "View group" permission.
- Go back to the Groups start page (/admin/group)
- Create a new group
- Click on your group name, then click Add member
- Add some members
- Log in as one of those members, go to your account, click the Group tab, click on "view group"
- Add some content

Now you have the basics of a group. Users, content, permissions and some ways to interact. Look through the rest of the tabs on all pages you visited, go into the detailed settings screens, activate more submodules, group roles, group permission etc. Extend using the group api hooks. Set up a suitable user interface using standard tools (views, VBO, rules, fields on the group).

For other settings you can visit following urls :

- https://www.drupal.org/node/2711123
- https://www.drupal.org/node/2711049
- https://www.drupal.org/node/2711119
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w2Ol19OzNAQ

**Drupal 8**

Watch [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GkiCLJk5n0s) video for a excellent and complete use-case configuration.

Hope [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GkiCLJk5n0s) will clear all doubt.